# Queuing sessions into the database

Tags: sqlalchemy, request, transactions, queue

I am trying to create an API that update data in the database Postgres SQLAlchemy with each request.
Each request recieved will call an update function that create a session using sessionmaker(), retrieve data from the database and update it and commit it back.
The problem arise when mutilples requests are sent in quick succession and later requests actually retrieve and update with the old data ( data that is not yet updated by the previous requests ).
For example for insert function, the 2nd request would check and find no entry and try to insert it before the 1st request can insert that entry into the database so there would be 2 entries with similar info in it.

I tried SQLAlchemy transaction but can't seem to get it working. I suspect it's because the session.execute() closed the transaction and start a new one before  running session.add() and in between them the other request would send it own session.execute() to check existence in the database

```
async def insert(session, bearer_token):
    newdbrow = Token()
    entity={"bearer_token":bearer_token,'id':uuid.uuid1(),'valid':True}
    for key, value in entity.items():
        setattr(newdbrow,key,value)
    async with session.begin():
        statement = select(Token).filter_by(bearer_token=bearer_token)
        rows = await session.execute(statement)
        rows = rows.scalars()
        row = next(rows, None)
        if row is None:
            session.add(newdbrow)
```

Edit: I tried to use isolation level at SERIALIZABLE and loop each request until it finished and it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an `upsert`, Insert but if it exists then update:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-upsert-statements

Also you might need to add a constraint so duplicate data cannot exist.

Comment: The model that I'm using also have attributes that are integer and would (ideally) be updated with every request so I really need the data that's received to be up-to-date.

Comment: You mean the data read from the db is up to date? (with regards to "the data that's received to be up-to-date")

Comment: For example, I want to add 1 to a value to the database each time a request comes in. The 1st request would read the data and update .the value from 5 to 6 but the 2nd request which also read the data before the 1st can finish update will perform a concurrent update and increase the value from 5 ( when it read it's 5) to 6 instead of 6 to 7. I just learnt about isolation level and am trying to shove it in my code somehow

Comment: You probably want to use row locking but if you have a lot of requests trying to do this simultaneously it is going to make them line up and wait for it.  Which not be ideal.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_for_update